# python Program is saying 2 numbers are different when they are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thanks for the help in advance.

I compare 2 variables which hold numbers with the operation !=

the program takes input like this

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

Then the program should return the highest product exluding a square product. In this case the result should be 12(4x3) not 16(4x4) but it is incorrectly returning 16.

The code is here

```
def max_pairwise_product():
    n = int(input())
    a = input().split()
    maxno = 0
    for integer1 in a:
        product = int(integer1) * n
        if n != integer1:
            if product > maxno:
                maxno = product


    return maxno


print(max_pairwise_product())
```

Comment: what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: @daniel - why do you complain about your progam returning 12 if thats the result you want to have? **should return the highest product exluding a square product. In this case the result should be 12(4x3) not 16(4x4) but it is incorrectly returning 12.**

Comment: Apologies It is a typo it should return 16 but it is sorted now

Answer (score 1):

You compare string vs. integer which is always `False`:

> ```
> for integer1 in a:                # integer1 is a string
>     product = int(integer1) * n
>     if n != integer1:             # n is a number
> ```

Fix:

```
def max_pairwise_product():
    _ = input() # not used 
    a = "1 2 3 4".split() # input() removed and fixed input given
    a = sorted(set(map(int,a)))   # convert all to intergers and sort unique numbers

    maxno = 0
    for idx,number in enumerate(a):
        for number2 in a[idx+1:]:
            maxno = max( maxno, number*number2 )

    return maxno

print(max_pairwise_product())
```

Output:

```
12
```

The loops are optimized leveraging the fact that they numbers are sorted and unique - thats why the second loop can be shorter - no need to recompute already computed results.

Its good if you get inputs like `'1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6'` because it will only compute for `'1 2 3 4 5 6'` and never compute any paring twice.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your comparing an `int` to a `str`. I have edited your code minimally to fix this issue, but you have better to edit your list input before hand.

```
def max_pairwise_product():
    n = int(input())
    a = input().split() #If I were you I would do: a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    maxno = 0
    for integer1 in a:
        product = int(integer1) * n
        if n != int(integer1): #This is were I have changed
            if product > maxno:
                maxno = product

    return maxno


print(max_pairwise_product())
```

Comment: @daniel it's probably because stackoverflow usually does not like to be asked to debug your codes for you.

Comment: @daniel one downvote is from me, see the comment below your post. you complain about getting 12 returned while your code _should_ return 12. thanks unclear.